# Chartboost More Apps: Different type of ads view in android

Tags: android, chartboost

I have integrate the charBoost Ads into My Application. Now i want to change the view from verticle to horizontal.

Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the view from vertical to horizontal by logging into the Chartboost dashboard ( https://dashboard.chartboost.com/ ), selecting "Overview" from the "Apps" hover-menu, and then clicking on your application name.

This will take you to the App Settings page where you can change the App Orientation to be either Landscape (horizontal) or Portrait (vertical), or both!

If you have any other questions you can always get help here: https://help.chartboost.com/

:)